# Is it possible to pack elements close together to optimize space usage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, packing

Is it possible to get the elements in the picture below to pack closer together somehow? Preferably using css, but javascript solutions are also welcome if that's not possible.

I'd like all the elements to be packed as closely together as possible to minimize the space they take up. The elements are currently spans with `display:inline-block`. I have tried to change to block with float:left, etc, but I always end up with inefficient rows of elements. That *is* the expected way, I'm just saying I'd like it to not be like that in this case :P

[image: elements]

Any brilliant minds able to help me out here?

Comment: The brilliant solution is to set the correct margins and paddings!

Comment: Do you know the height for each element? Can you reorder them in the HTML?

Comment: I can know, I suppose. Through jQuery/JS anyways. The images I can know, but the others are more tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're searching for a more sophisticated solution then look into jQuery `masonry` plugin. Link here: [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Now that looked interesting :D

Answer (score 2):

Freetile is perfect and simple :)
https://github.com/yconst/Freetile

Comment: Cool! Will try this next time :)